# How to replace part of a matched regular expression string in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, comments, replace

I want to replace a single word in the comments of my visual studio project. To find that word (lets say its "fun" I can use a regular expression like the following example (FYI, I am actually using spaces and not underscores, but put underscores here since they are easier to see)

```
^(:b*').*_fun_
```

That will find strings like this

```
'Oh how fun it is to ride
'You are fun to talk to
```

but it will not find

```
'You are so funny!
```

This is correct (its exactly what I want). What I want to know is how I can use use find/replace in VS to replace just the word " fun " with something else (lets say " interesting " for example's sake) such that the resulting comments end up as:

```
'Oh how interesting it is to ride
'You are interesting to talk to
'You are so funny!
```

Without having to individually replace each occurance of " fun " manually.

Incase its not clear, I just want to search and replace in the comments (which is what makes the regex search necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a tag that covers everything before `_fun_` and reference it in the replace statement. This will still only replace one occurrence of the word per line but it won't remove the other text.

**Find**

```
^{:b*'.*}<fun>
```

**Replace**

```
\1interesting
```

[Regular Expressions in VS2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

***-- EDIT --***

Use `<` and `>` to mark the beginning and end of a word. This way the regex should also match "fun" when it appears at the end of a line.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Could you suggest a regex/find-replace combo that will find all occurances of fun in a comment line and replace them all? Otherwise, I'll just run the same find/replace multiple times which should do the trick too (I think).

Comment: Not sure that is possible. At least not with my limited knowledge of Visual Studios find/replace.

Comment: Ok. I see that you edited your answer to include <> in the search. I'm confused as to why. Namely, could you name an instance where the search for <fun> would find something that simply "fun" (without the braces) wouldn't catch? If I understand correctly, adding the brackets restricts the search further, it does not make it wider.

Comment: " fun " (with spaces) would not match "This is fun" or "This is fun." while "<fun>" would.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below it will help you

```
ctrl + F - > Quick Replace

Find What ->{fun }
Replace With -> Interesting 
Find Options
Use RegularExpressions...
```

Comment: Thanks but you misunderstood the question. I'm not looking for code to replace strings at runtime. I am trying to use Visual Studio's find-replace functionality to replace words in comments.

Comment: thank you for your effort, however the search/find/quick-replace you suggested will search code and comments. I only want to search comments. Hsan's answer is what I was looking for.